# How to find if an element of a list is in another list?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I want to know if at least one element in a first list can be found in a second list.

I can see two ways to do it. Let's say our lists are:

```
List<string> list1 = new[] { "A", "C", "F", "H", "I" };
List<string> list2 = new[] { "B", "D", "F", "G", "I" };
```

The first approach uses a loop:

```
bool isFound = false;
foreach (item1 in list1)
{
    if (list2.Contains(item1))
    {
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The second one uses Linq directly:

```
bool isFound = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

The first one is long to write and not very straightforward/easy-to-read. The second one is short and clear, but performances will be low, especially on large lists.

What may be an elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think the second one will be faster for large lists.  Since the first one is `O(list1.Count*list2.Count)` whereas the second is `O(list1.Count+list2.Count)`. Second one takes more memory though.

Comment: If you really want to use LINQ to search *exactly* like your first sample, use `bool isFound = list1.Any(list2.Contains);`

Comment: But of course that variant, just like the original code has quadratic performance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The second one has better performance on large lists than the first one.  `Intersect` puts the elements of one list into a hash table before checking the other list's elements for membership.

Comment: I thought in the second case, the intersection of two lists will be calculated, and only then `Any` will be executed. Am I wrong?

Comment: The intersection is calculated lazily. I think it first creates a hashset out of list2 and then goes over list1 returning and adding to the hashset as it goes along.

Comment: @MainMa - yes, you are wrong on that. It will hash the *first* set, then use an iterator block to spool over the second. At each point you are only returning a single match. Iterator blocks do not run to completion before returning content. There is no need to calculate the full set of matches in a collection. The only time `Any()` would run to completion is if it returned `false` - otherwise it would short-circuit the sequence at the first match.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  You can imagine it as working in the same fashion that your `break` does in the loop.  The intersection is calculated lazily, and once the first element is found to be present in it, `Any()` returns and no more are checked.

Answer (score 9):

It seems odd to critique the performance of LINQ when the original is clearly (worst case) O(n*m); the LINQ approach would *I expect* use a `HashSet<T>` on a list, and then use a streaming iterator block - so the performance should be O(n+m) - i.e. better.

Answer (score 6):

I think the second one will be faster for large lists. Since the first one is O(list1.Count*list2.Count) whereas the second is O(list1.Count+list2.Count). Second one takes more memory though.

And the overhead of linq is typically a constant multiplication factor over handcrafted code. I'd guess the second one is slower than imperative code by at most a factor of two, probably not even that. It uses `O(list1.Count+list2.Count)` memory which can be cut down to `O(Min(list1,list2))` if you carefully write your code for low memory usage whilte retaining linear performance.

This code should be relatively fast on large lists:

```
bool isFound = false;
HashSet<string> set2=new HashSet<string>(list2);
foreach (item1 in list1)
{
    if (set2.Contains(item1))
    {
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can optimize this code further by making the smaller list into a hashset instead of always using list2.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is great, however it does not work with Linq-to-sql, since there's no mapping for `Intersect`.
In that case you should use :

```
bool isFound = table.Any(row => list2.Contains(row.FieldWithValue));
```

This gets compiled to `WHERE EXSITS`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to know if an element of one list exists in another list.

```
bool present = List1.Any(t => List2.Any(y => y == t));
```